# Create loops to write multiple graphs

Tags: r, loops, plot, ggplot2

I want to use a loop in order to create multiple plots for different values of DPC. The data I have looks like:

```
 df <- data.frame (c ("Results", "Capacity", "Power", "LDI","LDE", "LB", "PDC","D", CostPerkWh)
```

As output I would like multiple graphs with graphs for each unique value of PDC. 
The following plot work:

```
 plot1 <- ggplot(subset(df, df$PDC=='PDC0'),
   aes(Capacity, CostPerkWh))+ geom_point()+geom_line()
  plot2 <- ggplot(subset(df, df$PDC=='PDC0.25'),
            aes(Capacity, CostPerkWh))+ geom_point()+geom_line()
   plot3 <- ggplot(subset(df, df$PDC=='PDC0.5'),
            aes(Capacity, CostPerkWh))+ geom_point()+geom_line()
   plot4 <- ggplot(subset(df, df$PDC=='PDC0.75'),
            aes(Capacity, CostPerkWh))+ geom_point()+geom_line()
  plot5 <- ggplot(subset(df, df$PDC=='PDC1'),
            aes(Capacity, CostPerkWh))+ geom_point()+geom_line()
```

All these plots work,however I would like to create a loop since I have a large amount of parameters and I found this [example](http://www.reed.edu/data-at-reed/resources/R/loops_with_ggplot2.html).

So I tried to implement it into my own model:

```
#plot data
StoreResults <- "/Users/IMA/Documents/Results/"
    PDC.graph <- function(df, na.rm = TRUE, ...){
      PDClist <- unique(df$PDC) 
      for (i in seq_along(PDClist)){
        plot <- 
          ggplot(subset(df, df$PDC==PDClist[i]),
                 aes(Capacity, CostPerkWh)) + geom_point()+
          ggtitle(paste(PDClist, 'PDC, Power  \n', "Capacity \n", sep='')) + 
          geom_line() 
        print(plot)
        #save plot as PNG 
        ggsave(plot, file= paste(StoreResults, '/projection_graphs/PDCgraph/',
                                 PDClist[i], ".png", sep=''), scale=2)
      }
    }
```

The code does not give me an error message, but I don't see any graphs and  nothing gets stored into the folder that is defined; how to resolve this? Or is there a better way to export many graph for different values of PDC?

Comment: Check the definition of `df`. Something is missing.

Comment: Not sure how you are naming your files but you might be missing a `/` after the `StoreResults` or before `projection_graphs`

Comment: Try commenting the `ggsave` line

Comment: @timfaber I added the / but it's still not working. @MarcoSandri I changed the df in order to post it, but I don't think anything is wrong with the df snce the plot does appear when I use this code  `plot1 <- ggplot(subset(df, df$PDC=='PDC0'),
   aes(Capacity, CostPerkWh))+ geom_point()+geom_line()`. @Hacherman could you explain what you mean with try comment the ggaveline? The plot also does not appear from the print(plot) line so I'm not sure if anything is wrong with the save as PNG part.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't you forget running the function you created?
This minimal version works for me:

```
df = iris

StoreResults <- "/Users/timfaber/Desktop"
PDC.graph <- function(df, na.rm = TRUE, ...){
  PDClist <- unique(df$Species) 
  for (i in seq_along(PDClist)){

      ggplot(subset(iris, df$Species==PDClist[i]),
      aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point() +
      ggtitle(paste(PDClist[i], 'PDC, Power  \n', "Capacity \n", sep=''))

    #save plot as PNG 
    ggsave(plot = last_plot(), file= paste(StoreResults, '/etc/',
                             PDClist[i], ".png", sep=''), scale=2)
  }
}

PDC.Graph(df)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the issue!.